# Why am I still getting the Php warning on mac after I made sure to install brew install php?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

When I typed in `php -v`, I still get this warning:

> WARNING: PHP is not recommended PHP is included in macOS for
> compatibility with legacy software. Future versions of macOS will not
> include PHP. PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built:
> Dec 21 2020 21:33:25) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

So I ran `brew install php` and then tried again with `php -v` but I'm still getting this warning.

What should I do? I need to install composer after this...

Comment: This just looks like a deprecation warning. Probably PHP stopped giving Apple the backhander

Comment: "WARNING: PHP is not recommended [complete lack of context of any recommendation or lack thereof]" = ignore it.

Comment: PHP is installed if that is what you are worrying about. If it wasnt then `php -v` would say a lot less, something like `command php not found`

Comment: It looks like in the next OS update, PHP won't be installed anymore. So if you need it then, you must install by yourself.

Comment: @RiggsFolly what about checking out which version your php have?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the brew install PHP just restart the terminal